# How to hide bootstrap hamburger icon onclick/tap?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

How do I hide the hamburger icon when a user clicks or taps the icon on mobile? I assume I have to set it to display: none, but not sure how to do it with JavaScript. Don't worry, for usability I have the close button on the mobile drop menu. Is there an easy way to do this? I have googled but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: And, where's your code?

Comment: You must share some code / mockup for the same, from the description nothing is clear.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm under NDA and can't post a link to the site. I'm using Bootstrap framework though.

Comment: Maybe you should read this? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or maybe you could make a simple example for people to work with? No source code = nothing to debug, nothing to debug = nothing to solve or answer.

Comment: Thanks for being not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you're asking, I'll just make a guess that you want to hide an element when a user clicks on it. I'd rather use jQuery:

```
$("[icon]").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: You might "rather" use jQuery but jQuery isn't tagged in this question....

Comment: But it is Bootstrap, so why would be a problem

Comment: @NewToJS  I'm assuming the OP is using the full Bootstrap framework with the JS files, therefore he must have jQuery

Comment: This is what this answer are suggesting, looks fine: https://jsfiddle.net/4swcy68x/

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for!